# Conversion from scala parallel collection to regular collection

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-collections

I'm trying to convert back from a parallel collection to a regular map. According to the api, if I call toMap on any appropriately defined parallel collection, it's supposed to return a standard Map, but it's returning ParMap over a flattened collection of iterables.

I have a

```
val task: Stream[Future[Iterable[Tuple2[String, String]]]]
```

And from which I get:

```
val res: ParSeq[Iterable[Tuple2[String, String]]] = tasks.par.map(f => f.apply())
```

Finally:

```
val finalresult = res.flatten.toMap
```

Unfortunately, the type of `finalresult` is `ParMap[String, String]`.

On the other hand, if I call it like:

```
tasks.par.map(f => f.apply()).reduce(_++_).toMap
```

then the return type is `Map[String, String]`.

Can someone tell me why this is? And (out of curiosity) how I can force convert a `ParMap` to a `Map` when scala won't let me?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As you go explicitly from sequential to parallel collection via `.par`, you go back to sequential via `.seq`. Since sets and maps have parallel implementations, `toMap` and `toSet` calls leave the collection in the current domain.

The example of `reduce` works because it, well, reduces the collection (the outer `ParSeq` disappears, leaving you with the inner (sequential) `Iterable[Tuple2[...]]`).