# convert scala parallel collection back to regular sequence

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

How can a Parallel sequence:

```
Seq(1,2,3).par.map(_ +1)
```

be converted back to a regular sequence?

[Conversion from scala parallel collection to regular collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023045/conversion-from-scala-parallel-collection-to-regular-collection) mentions that a reduce should work but:

```
Seq(1,2,3).par.map(_ +1).reduce(_++_).toSeq
```

will not compile. There is an option of calling `toArray` though. But I believe there must be a better way returning back to a regular collection

I need to have a solution for 2.11.

Comment: At least until **2.12** there was a `.seq` method that would return the same collection, but sequentially. _(Anyways, I believe it still has to build a new collection, if that is what you want to avoid)_.

Comment: No, it will return a parallel match.

Comment: Care to explain what you mean with that? - for **2.11** you can use the [`seq` method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.11/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable@seq:Sequential) as I said.

Comment: I see. I was mixing up `toSeq` and `seq`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert [par collection to seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.11/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike)

```
Seq(1,2,3).par.map(_ +1).seq
```